# '@layout' isn't locating resources in the XML implementation of the ExpandableLayout from ExpandableLayout library

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, expandable

When I try and build the grade I get these errors, both of the same kind, in the XML:

Error:(16) No resource identifier found for attribute 'headerLayout' in package 'com.example.heavymagikhq.expandablelayoutlibrary'

Error:(16) No resource identifier found for attribute 'contentLayout' in package 'com.example.heavymagikhq.expandablelayoutlibrary'

Both indicate the '@layout' function isn't working in this XML code:

```
 <com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        expandable:headerLayout="@layout/view_header"   -------> Not working 
        expandable:contentLayout="@layout/view_content" ------->Not working
        android:background="#e74c3c"/>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why was this downvoted  ? It is not very helpful to downvote without saying why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to replace this

```
expandable:el_headerLayout="@layout/view_header"
expandable:el_contentLayout="@layout/view_content"
```

instead of

```
expandable:headerLayout="@layout/view_header"   
expandable:contentLayout="@layout/view_content"
```

if it still doesn't work try to import the lib directly to your project instead of using gradle

i used to face the same problem and this solution works fine :D

Comment: yo! Sorry for the late response. This was indeed the correct answer, thank you very much for the help. I had tried switching the xml statements as you suggested, but the thing which did it in the end was importing the library. Thanks again !